# Need Help in send news letter using PHP mail function

Tags: php, sendmail

Need your help in over coming the following issues.

1. i need to send opt-in newsletters to the user. But using "gmail SMTP", i will not be able to send more than 400 mails per day.
2. Even if i use the mail option given in the shared server, i will not be able to send mails more than 300 mails per day.

Can you please suggest any other way i can handle this issue. Is it possible to use PHP mail functions? are there any limitations in sending the number of mails to the users.

can a server control the mails sent using PHP mail function.

Thanks for reading.

thanks a lot

Comment: first, what are you doing to ensure true "opt-in"?

Comment: have you considered generating an RSS feed instead? receiving an email daily in the form of a "newsletter" can be annoying. you don't have a guarantee either that the user is just sending your emails to a spam folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation on the number of mails you can send per day/hour is set by your SMTP server. In case of the mail() function, it is once again set by your host. If you wish to remove this limitation, generally you would:

1. Talk to your host's tech support and
   ask them to raise the limit. Some
   hosts like Fatcow raise your limit
   from 500 to about 5000 (don't remember the exact numbers).
2. You can buy a dedicated virtual
   server with no such restriction,
   where the limit would only be the
   speed at which you could send your
   emails.
3. You can try newsletter mailing
   software/add-ons like
   ConstantContact that help you manage
   your newsletters effectively.

Answer (score 1):

1- you can buy vps and send many mail

2- you can buy smtp server for many sent

3- you can buy valid ip and set in your pc ... run somethings like postfix and sent mail in this way ...

Answer (score 1):

Use an smtp relay service. I've had good experiences with smtp.com in the past (I'm not affiliated with them in any way). You can grab a library to connect to it and get going relatively fast.

Answer (score 1):

Yuou should check this link http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/server-smtp-limit.html

Every server comes with its own smtp/mail limit, usually 300-500 for shared and between 500 and 2k for dedicated. This is by ICAN regulations i believe to control spam as much as possible.

Most of the dedicated servers out there will increase your mail/smtp relay limit on a request mentioning why you need to increase,etc. You will also need to include an unsubscribe link in the newsletter so that users who recieve the mail can opt out from future mails.

Increasing the mail limit is sequential usually and it can be upto 100,000 on a godaddy dedicated server from what i got from chat support @go daddy.

As for gmail smtps, you can't send more than 500 a day and 2000 for business/educational google apps account.